# How do I load the functions of a JavaScript File called through a JavaScript Object

Tags: javascript

I have a local JS file that needs to be called using a script object. However, I am not able to get the functions to run. Here's the code snippet.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
 var x = document.createElement("SCRIPT");
 x.type = "text/javascript";
 x.src = "file:///C:/scripts/localscript.js";
 //one of the functions is loadData();
 loadData(); //I'm getting reference error, loadData is not defined.
</script>
```

Thank you,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to create a `script` element and insert it in `DOM (mostly under head)` to load the script. When that script is loaded by the browser, whatever you return from that script will be available.

Consider `sampleScript.js` with below code

```
(function(window){
  'use strict';

  window.app = {
    sayHi: function() {
      console.log('Hey there !');
    }

  };

})(this);
```

To load this script, I do

```
<script>
   var node = document.createElement('script');
   node.src = 'sampleScript.js';
   node.addEventListener('load', onScriptLoad, false);
   node.async = true;
   document.head.appendChild(node);

   function onScriptLoad(evt) {
     console.log('Script loaded.');
     console.log('app.sayHi ---> ');
     app && app.sayHi();
   }
</script>
```

Taking cues, you can fit to your need. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Use the `onload` event:

```
x.onload = function() { window.loadData(); }
```